# JavaFX 8: In a TableColumn, setPrefWidth does not work after user manually resizes column

Tags: javafx, tableview

JavaFX 8:

I have a TableView. I want to let users decide the column width either with the mouse (column.setResizable(true)) or with a dialog, where they can manually input the number of pixels. This all works, but here's my problem:

Sometimes, the prefWidth and the Width of the column differ. In particular, if the user manually resizes the column and then uses the dialog to input a pixel width which is minor than the manually set width, the width doesn't change even if I call setPrefWidth. The code is correct, because the prefWidth is correctly set (I read them using getPrefWidth and getWidth and they don't match after using setPrefWidth).

For example, the prefWidth will be 200 and the actual width 100. But I need to give my users the chance to change the width in both ways, in any order.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. This makes it easier for people to debug and offer a solution to your question.

Comment: Hi, and thanks. Sadly, my example would be very complex and long to add... But I can write the methods I'm calling:

TableColumn.setPrefWidth
TableColumn.getPrefWidth
TableColumn.getWidth

Why isn't there a setWidth?